# JQuery Click on Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
<div class="contentContainer">
        <div class="bild" id="bildDiv">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server">
            </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>
            <div class="menubox" id="menuboxID">
                <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" class="menutable">
                    <tr>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton1" CssClass="menuitem" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons_Home.png"
                                OnClick="HomeClick" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton2" CssClass="menuitem" data-ftrans="slide" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons_down.png"
                                OnClick="DownClick" runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton3" CssClass="menuitem" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons_up.png"
                                runat="server" OnClick="UpClick" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton4" CssClass="menuitem" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons_Video_alternative.png"
                                runat="server" />
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="ImageButton5" CssClass="menuitem" ImageUrl="~/Images/Icons_Mail.png"
                                runat="server" OnClick="MailClick" />


                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    <script>
        $("#bildDiv").click(function () {

            $("#menuboxID").toggleClass("fadein");
        });
        $('body').removeClass('ui-loading');
   </script>
```

So when I click on my #bildDiv, #menuboxID will be faded in! But now I have some textboxes in my #bildDiv! When I click on any textbox in order to write sth, my Menu fades in! But I don't want it to...it should only fade in if I click directly on my div! Solutions?

Comment: You may want to think about how your user interface is laid out. If you have text boxes inside of a div that is supposed to open a menu, this may be confusing to the user. You might want to think about making the menu open by something more apparent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following.

```
$("#bildDiv INPUT").click(function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Stop the propagation of the event using the [stopPropgation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/event.stopPropagation) method:

```
$("#bildDiv input").click(function (e) {
     e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: Your Solution made my day...Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use Faded in effect in Menubar only. Attach click event to #menuboxID not to #bildDiv.

```
$("#menuboxID").click(function () {

    $("#menuboxID").toggleClass("fadein");
});
```